# PebbleFramework is giving me a ton of warnings and errors

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, external-accessory, pebble-watch

I took an old game that I had and wanted to add the PebbleFramework and now I am getting these warnings and errors. I followed their documentation correctly.

Any help would greatly be appreciated

```
Ld /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TicTacToe.app/TicTacToe normal i386
    cd /Users/developer/Developer/iOS/TicTac
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/developer/Developer/iOS/TicTac -F/Users/developer/Downloads/TicTac -filelist /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Intermediates/TicTacToe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TicTacToe.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToe.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -framework CoreLocation -lz -framework ExternalAccessory -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreMotion -framework MessageUI -framework GameKit -framework iAd -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AdSupport -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework PebbleVendor -framework PebbleKit -framework Foundation -framework RevMobAds -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Intermediates/TicTacToe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TicTacToe.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToe_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjyphzfzstogbbegocrpujgsfhxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TicTacToe.app/TicTacToe

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/developer/Downloads/TicTac'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork", referenced from:
      -[QServer netService:didNotPublish:] in PebbleKit(QServer.o)
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetServices", referenced from:
      -[QServer netService:didNotPublish:] in PebbleKit(QServer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below are the instructions that I followed when adding the PebbleKit framework.

```
## Integrating PebbleKit Manually

- Drag PebbleKit.framework into project
- Drag in PebbleVendor.framework into the project, or, drag the PebbleVendor.xcodeproj into project if you need to control the 3rd party components needed for PebbleKit.
- Link ExternalAccessory.framework, libz.dylib, CoreBluetooth.framework, CoreMotion.framework and MessageUI.framework
- Add "-ObjC" linker flag to your project's build settings
- Add the value "com.getpebble.public" to the "Supported external accessory protocols" (UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols) array in your app's Info.plist
- Optionally, add the value "App communicates with an accessory" (external-accessory) to the "Required background modes" (UIBackgroundModes) array in your app's Info.plist
```

Comment: The instructions you followed are outdated. Can you let us know where you found them? Up-to-date instructions are available here: https://developer.getpebble.com/2/mobile-app-guide/ios-guide.html/

Comment: Please provide your comment as an answer so I can give your answer the checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you followed are outdated. Can you let us know where you found them?

Up-to-date instructions are available here: http://developer.getpebble.com/2/mobile-app-guide/ios-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `CFNetwork` is also linked to your app.